# "For most" vs "of many" Idiomatic Language

Tags: word-choice, idioms

For example, which choice of idiomatic language would best serve the meaning of this particular sentence?

> My friend Allan is typical **for most** **/** **of many** programmers today in that he ponders for hours on the computer.

Comment: Also verify that *ponder* is really the word you're looking for-  *Pondering* isn't really something one does on the computer.

Comment: @Jim, the OP is using "on" in the sense of "about". The dissonance comes from "*the* computer" and the idiomaticity of the phrase "on the computer" meaning "working on the computer". In context, the sense the OP is (possibly) using, 'on' = 'about', might be clear. I'm glad you pointed out the potential problem, though; I started to include that observation in my answer, but rejected it because it assumed too much about the omitted context without justification. So a comment is the place for the observation.

Comment: @JEL- YOu may be right, but I know quite a few programmers, and I'd guess that maybe 2 out of 100 actually ponder about computers. We tend to ponder about algorithms and architectures and solutions but rarely on the computers themselves.

Comment: @Jim, That's true--I'm just saying that it can't be assumed on the basis of what we know about the OP and the context. Maybe Allan works for the Babbage Institute? Maybe the OP goes on to say, or has already said "Allan is often preoccupied by consideration of the nature of computers" or something equivalent that makes the intended sense of "on" clear *in context*.

Comment: @Jim, also note that the comments would be an appropriate place to ask the OP for more information: "Do you mean Allan ponders about the computer, or do you mean Allan ponders [something] while using a computer?

Comment: Does it really matter what he's pondering about to answer the question about the appropriate preposition? The same question could be asked without the phrase starting with _in that_.

Comment: I would put it this way: "Like many programmers today, my friend Allan ponders for hours on the computer." Or rather, I would do that if I felt comfortable with the phrase "ponders ... on the computer," which I don't. Are you thinking of the verb _putters_ here?

Answer (score 1):

I should think that the choice of words/ing would depend on the scope intended: where 'most' (superlative) gives the idea of a majority having that tendency, hence an almost characteristic trait shared by all, while 'many' (quantitative) hints at a recurrent tendency, but not necessarily an indicative one.

Answer (score 0):

Your "typical of" is idiomatic in the context you provide, and works well, whether you use "typical of most" or "typical of many". Unless you can justify quantifying "many" as "most" (where 'many' is more than half), however, I recommend against using "most", just to ward off quibblers.

Comment: You can also leave out the quantifier entirely, i.e. _typical of programmers_. Of course, the word _typical_ itself implies that something is very common.

Comment: @Barmar, of course you cannot leave out the modifier, without modifying the meaning of the phrase. "Typical of all programmers", for example, means something quite different than typical of some, a few, most or many. Even in that example, "all programmers", the signifier 'all' cannot be omitted without changing the meaning. I suppose you assume you know what the OP intended, without context to support your assumption? "Chauvinistic attitudes are typical of programmers" means something different (and less supportable) than "chauvinistic attitudes are typical of many/most/some programmers".